# Dropdownlist not bound in dim background

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

In my web page I show loading image with dim background. Dropdown list is not bound inside the dim background .In IE only I experience this problem..How to fix it..

Comment: Your question is really vague. Can you post some code to help us understand your problem?

Comment: I can't able to attach the screen shot to share with you..I don't know how to explain my need sorry ... sorry for my poor english

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropdown list not bound in dim background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913320/dropdown-list-not-bound-in-dim-background)

Comment: This version has exactly the same lack of details as your previous (closed) one.

Comment: You should probably spend a while browsing the site so you can get the feel for how to ask a good question that will attract good answers

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you are using Internet Explorer 6.  It has a problem where dropdown lists are always shown above all other elements in the page.  There are some [workarounds for this](http://www.tinyqueen.com/web-site-design/ie6-select-z-index-bug-a-workaround), but I would recommend simply upgrading your browser, as this bug is fixed in IE7 and later.

Comment: yes.  upgrade your browser.  IE6 is ten years old.  Nobody should be using it anymore.